# connect linux kubuntu from windows xp through vnc

Tags: windows-xp, kubuntu, vnc-viewer

I want to connect my linux(kubuntu machine) from windows XP machine through VNC viewer in LAN.
Can I do this in GUI mode? If possible, how to do this? Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try [TigerVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/). I use it regularly to access my openSuse 11.4 installation from Windows XP, and it works great. Not much to it. Just read the tutorial on the site and you're good to go...

On my linux box, I run the command:

```
dbus-launch vncserver :1 -depth 8 -geometry 800x600
```

And then from the TigerVNC viewer, I connect to my linux systems IP like:

```
192.168.1.1:1
```

Note the :1 at the end. It should be the same number as the one you gave in the dbus-launch command.

[Here's](http://opensuse.swerdna.org/susetightvnc.html) a link to the tutorial I mentioned. It's for openSuse but should be helpful enough for most linux distros.

Hope that helps...